# Rest django checking the duplicate number

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

if i inserting the number 5 i want to check all the numbers before 5( like 1,2,3 and 4 )is must have inside the db ,then only can i add the number 5 ,otherwise show error. And also check is any duplication in the Db using rest django model serilaizer.

```
def validate_match_round(self, match_round):
    if not match_round :
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Enter value more than 0 ")
```

matchscore model

```
class Matchscore(TimeStampedModel):
gameevent = models.ForeignKey(GameEvent, null=True, related_name='game_event',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
match_round = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_a = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_one',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_a_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_b = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_two',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
team_b_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
team_won = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)



    if match_round == 1:
        return match_round
    match = Matchscore.objects.aggregate(Max('match_round'))
    print(match)
    if match_round == match["match_round__max"] + 1 :
        return match_round
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Enter a valid match_round")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all_rounds = Matchscore.objects.filter(match_round__lte=match_round).order_by('match_round').values_list('match_round', flat=True)
```

Will return list of `match_round` values that lower or equal than `match_round` passed to function

```
all_rounds_count = Matchscore.objects.filter(match_round__lte=match_round).count()
```

Will return count of these rounds. and `if (all_rounds_count + 1) == match_round` check is what you want

> And also check is any duplication in the Db using rest django model serilaizer.

To avoid keys duplication

1. Set `unique=True` for `model.Field` to disable round duplicates `match_round = models.IntegerField(..., unique = True)`
2. Add [unique validator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator) to serializer

Comment: also i want to check each number  must have in the db ,before entered number

Comment: there is no limit for inserting the match_round

Comment: @megha is `match_round` number unique inside DB?

Comment: each gameevent has match_rounds but one gameevent only allow match_round_1 one time ,actually i figure it out that is working. i will share the code.

Comment: def create(self, validated_data):
        gameevent = validated_data.get('gameevent')
        match_round =validated_data.get('match_round')
        match = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent,match_round=match_round).first()
        if match :
            validated_data = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent,match_round=match_round).update(**validated_data)
            match.refresh_from_db()
            return match
        else:
            return Matchscore.objects.create(**validated_data)

Comment: my actual requirement is each gameevent has match_round ,but one gameevnt has only one match_round at a time if match round 2 it will create as new data , and if for a gameevnt1 adding matchround 100 ,then round  99 will must have in the db. check each round is present ,not only 99 but also all numbers before 100 check it seperately

Comment: @megha will be better if you reformat your question and add additional information (at least `Matchscore` model)

Comment: ok i will add the matchscore model